# Laravel 5.1 - Facebook through Socialite (Client Error: 400)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

Using [this tutorial on Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/9) (Laravel 5.0 - Socialite), specifically until *min 12.11*, I have successfully setup everything. However, I am using Laravel 5.1

- Defined my route but currently commented out the callback provider, as I am just trying to fetch the user details through taken token:

  ```
  Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
  //Route::get('auth/facebook/aaa', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
  ```
- Added necessities in `config>services.php`:

  ```
  'facebook' => [
   'client_id' => '##',
   'client_secret' => env('FB_SECRET_ID'),
   'redirect' => 'http://laratest.dev/auth/facebook',   
  ],
  ```

I decided to return to the same page (`auth/facebook`) for now. That's why I have set the return as `domain.devv/auth/facebook` for testing.

- In my `AuthController.php`, I set:

  ```
  public function redirectToProvider(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request)
   {  
     return $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'));
   }
  ```
- And finally, in my `AuthenticateUser.php`:

  ```
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;  (PS. I changed Authenticator to Guard)

     class AuthenticateUser {
        private $users;
        private $socialite;
        private $auth;

  public function __construct(UserRepository $users, Socialite $socialite, Guard $auth)
   {
       $this->users = $users;
       $this->socialite = $socialite;
       $this->auth = $auth;
   } 

  public function execute($hasCode)
   {   
     // dd($hasCode) *First dd

    if ( ! $hasCode) return $this->getAuthorizationFirst();

    // $user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();

    // dd($hasCode) *Second dd
    // dd($user) *Third dd
   }

  private function getAuthorizationFirst()
   {
     return $this->socialite->driver('facebook')
       ->scopes(['public_profile', 'email'])->redirect();
   } 
  }
  ```

---

Now, I am clicking `Login with Facebook` link and getting directed to `domain.dev/auth/facebook?code=943299043290...`

When I use only the `*First dd` (with all the other commented lines are commented)- it returns `false`.

When I use the only the `*Second dd` (with commenting the line `$user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();`), it returns `true`.

So everything is working perfect and goes through `execute()`, then through `getAuthorizationFirst()`. Finally, returns back to `execute()` with the taken token which is also contained in the link (`domain.dev/auth/facebook?code=943299043290...`).

---

**My problem arises here:**

At the second I am uncommenting `$user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();`, I am getting an error:

> ClientException in Middleware.php line 69: Client error: 400
>
> *1. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laratest/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php line 69*
>
> *2. at Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(object(Response)) in Promise.php line 199*
>
> *3. at Promise::callHandler('1', object(Response), array(object(Promise), object(Closure), null)) in Promise.php line 152*
>
> *4. at Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() in TaskQueue.php line 60*
>
> *5. at TaskQueue->run() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 96*

this line (`$user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();`) is **not working** for me for some reasons (while it does in the [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/9) (*min 12.11 for 15-second brief explanation*).

Whenever I use `$user = $this->socialite->driver('facebook')->user();`, I receive the error *`ClientException in Middleware.php line 69: Client error: 400`* and, of course, I can't get `dd($user)`.

To add, when I see the ClientException error, the link is still with the code: (`domain.dev/auth/facebook?code=943299043290...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was having this issue too, in my case i have to add my domain in config/session.php in the domain field and add it too in my app provider